# Cake 2.0 CLI mode error "Undefined HTTP_HOST "

Tags: shell, cakephp, command-line-interface

I am Running a shell script on cake console. Able to run **HelloShell** But getting error undefined `HTTP_host` on `app/config/core.php` for following code:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses=array('Test');
    public function main() {
        $this->out('Hello Kundan.');
    }
     public function hey() {
       $this->Test->save($data['Test']['name']='Kundan');
    }
}
```

bellow the error message:

```
PHP notice: undefined index HTTP_HOST in 
C:\wamp\www\myapplication\app\Config\core.php on line 231.
```

When I opened that file I found following on line number 231 `Configure::write('Website_root',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);`

Comment: can you add error message to your question?

Comment: PHP notice: undefined index HTTP_HOST in C:\wamp\www\myapplication\app\Config\core.php on line 231.

(When i opened that file i found following on line number 231
Configure::write('Website_root',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 

 )

Answer (score 0):

I have replicate your code, and it run well.

where do you put `HelloShell.php` file? and how do you run your code?.

The common way, put your `HelloShell.php` file in `app/Console/Command/` directory and run it by `Console/cake hello`

also try to modify your code:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {

    public $uses=array('Test');

    public function main() {
        $this->out('Hello Kundan.');
        $this->hey();
    }
     public function hey() {
       $data['Test']['name']='Kundan';
       $this->Test->save($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did same. As i mentioned I am able to run simple Hello progarm.

Comment: are you able to save data..?I'm getting this problem. 

And I am using cakephp's 2.0 version.

Comment: Yes, I can save. look at modified answer.

Comment: Please consider this question as closed. Actually I myself defined a variable inside core.php. for Host name. That is why it was showing error. 

Now for host name I am hardcoding it on controller. And working fine.